# Is it possible in Keras to use the inputs of a neural network in a following custom layer again?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

For a personal Layer at the end of the network I need the inputs of the first Layer again. Is it possible to use the same inputs twice?
In the last final personal Layer I need the inputs of the model which contains the changeable values for
a,b and c to do a final matrix multiplication. The problem is that the matrix will change in every step, because a,b and c are always different.

```
class PersonalLayer(Layer): 
   def __init__(self):
       super(PersonalLayer, self).__init__()
       
   def call(self, input_data): # Calculation of the matrix multiplication
       a= #input_data_model(0,1) and the values a,b,c should be float numbers for the following matrix generation
       b= #input_data_model(0,2)
       c= #input_data_model(0,3)
       matrix= matrix= tf.constant([[a*b*3,a+b,b**2]])
       prediction = tf.matmul(matrix,input_data)
       return prediction

input_data_model = keras.Input(shape=(10,))
x = layers.Dense(32,activation="relu") (input_data)
x = layers.Dense(64,activation="relu") (x)
x = layers.Dense(3,activation="sigmoid") (x)
output = PersonalLayer()(x) 

model = keras.Model(inputs=[input_data_model], outputs=output, name="Test")
model.summary()
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example with valid code and maybe some example data. Not with commented, but actually necessary function calls. Its easier to talk about concrete problems. If you have changing dimensions, make sure to multiply the correct matrices, this is non trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible:

```
class PersonalLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer): 
   def __init__(self):
       super(PersonalLayer, self).__init__()
       
   def call(self, input_data): # Calculation of the matrix multiplication
      a = input_data[1][0,1]
      b = input_data[1][0,2]
      c = input_data[1][0,3]
      matrix = tf.stack([a*b*3, a+b, b**2])[tf.newaxis, ...]
      prediction = tf.matmul(matrix, tf.transpose(input_data[0]))
      return prediction 

input_data = keras.Input(shape=(10,))
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(32,activation="relu") (input_data)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(64,activation="relu") (x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(3,activation="sigmoid") (x)
output = PersonalLayer()((x, input_data)) 

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[input_data], outputs=output, name="Test")
model.summary()
inp = tf.random.uniform((10, 10))
a = model(inp)
```

Comment: Yes, this is right, but I need the outputs from the last Dense Layer and the Inputs from the beginning.

Comment: thank you! So in the call function input_data[0] stands for the x and input_data[1] stands for the input_data or how can I access the two different inputs individually?

Comment: yes, input_data[0] stands for the `x`, input_data[1] stands  for the `input_data`

Comment: Thanks! From the input_data[1] which contains ten diffrent numbers I need the values with the index 0,1,2 for the ```tf.constant([[a*b*3,a+b,b**2]])``` but ```a=tf.gather_nd(input_data[1],[0,0])``` doesn't work. And this generated matrix should be multiplied with the ```input_data[0]``` Do you have an idea how to do it?

Comment: try `a = input_data[1][0,1]`